# docker node app always crashes on file change using nodemon

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

I am using the latest version of docker and the latest node image. I have a gulpfile that starts a nodemon process. I am using the --inspect flag to indicate I want to use the experimental chrome dev tool debugger. But when I make a file change it nodemon picks it up and restarts the process but crashes.

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('start:dev', done => {
  let started = false;
  nodemon({
    script: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js'),
    ext: 'js json',
    nodeArgs: ['--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229'],
    watch: path.join(__dirname, 'express'),
    legacyWatch: true
  })
  .on('start', () => {
    // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
    if (!started) {
      setTimeout(() => done(), 100);
      started = true;
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the error:

`Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use`

If I change the `--inspect` flag to be `--debug` it works like a charm.

I am guessing is that the restart process is too fast for the `--inspect` to release its port. If I make another file change it does work and restarts normally. Probably since it had time to release the port.

I have tried using a delay on nodemon but I'd rather not. I would like quick restarts. And I have tried using to events, like, restart and exit, to wait for a few seconds and then restart the whole gulp task. But that was temperamental and again I want quick restarts without having to hack together something.

Right now I just switched back to `--debug` but that is deprecated in the latest V8. They are recommending to use `--inspect`.

Maybe the only way is to lock down my version of node?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found the only way was to use `kill-port` as recommended below. Hardly a great solution, but it *is* working...

Answer (score 4):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1476) addressing this problem.

The easiest workaround I found so far was using `"signal": "SIGINT"` in my nodemon.json thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1346#issuecomment-497130305).

Answer (score 1):

Just kill inspector and start inspector again
here is our team's solution in our `package.json`.
You had better kill inspector process and then restart inspector

`` "inspect": "kill-port --port 9229 && node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 build/startup.js",
"start_watch_inspect": `nodemon --delay 80ms --watch build/ build/startup.js --exec 'npm run inspect'` ``

Comment: Please look into the way you formatted your answer. These triple single quotes " ' " - are they part of the answer?! Formatting matters!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is related to:
https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1492

My workaround is to run this before each restart: (in a makefile, gulp file etc...)

```
lsof -i -n | grep 9229 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

** If put inside a Makefile remember to replace $ with $$ **